# Total value of objects with the same name in php

Tags: php

I'm having a problem:
I'm try to total all value same "id" in json
Example:

```
[{id: "100002475575341", name: "N1", point: "2"},
 {id: "100002993363229", name: "N2", point: "2"},
 {id: "100002993363229", name: "N2", point: "2"},
 {id: "100002475575341", name: "N1", point: "2"}]
```

and expected result:

```
[{id: "100002475575341", name: "N1", point: "4"},
 {id: "100002993363229", name: "N2", point: "4"}]
```

Comment: what you want as result ?

Comment: @MohammedYassineCHABLI It says it there in the question..?

Comment: what code you use and is the result the result you get or the result you want to get,

Comment: Do you get the data from Database? If so.. better do it on db side

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the question is about seeking code help without showing any effort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Note: I changed your JSON string to be valid, by adding quotes around the indexed names*

Decode the JSON into an array, then loop it. Add it into an `$results` array, indexed by `name`. If the element exists, add the points together. If it doesn't exist, create it.

```
$json = '[{"id": "100002475575341", "name": "N1", "point": "2"},
          {"id": "100002993363229", "name": "N2", "point": "2"},
          {"id": "100002993363229", "name": "N2", "point": "2"},
          {"id": "100002475575341", "name": "N1", "point": "2"}]';

$array = json_decode($json);
$result = [];

foreach ($array as $a) {
    if (isset($result[$a->name])) {
        $result[$a->name]->point += $a->point;
    } else {
        $result[$a->name] = $a;
    }
}

$output = json_encode(array_values($result));
```

- Live demo at https://3v4l.org/CVOmt

Answer (score 0):

I use your code as example, You can try this

NOTE : I change your JSON as it is invalid JSON format.

```
<?php   

  $jsonString = '[{
      "id": "100002475575341",
      "name": "N1",
      "point": "2"
    },
    {
      "id": "100002993363229",
      "name": "N2",
      "point": "2"
    },
    {
      "id": "100002993363229",
      "name": "N2",
      "point": "2"
    },
    {
      "id": "100002475575341",
      "name": "N1",
      "point": "2"
    }
  ]';

  $jsonDecoded = json_decode($jsonString, true);

  $res = [];
  foreach ($jsonDecoded as $value) {
    if(array_key_exists($value['id'], $res)){
        $res[$value['id']] += $value['point'];
    }else{
        $res[$value['id']] = $value['point'];
    }
  }
  print_r($res);

?>
```